# rake db:createでエラーが発生する

Tags: ruby, rake

Thingspeakをhttps://github.com/iobridge/thingspeakからgit cloneしてbundle installしました。
このThingSpeakはバージョンが古いのでGitのIssuesに記載されていた方法を用いました
(URL:https://github.com/iobridge/thingspeak/issues/56)

但し依存関係の問題でTzinfo-dataはGemfileからコメントアウトしました。
その後rakeをapt-getでインストールし以下のコマンドを実行しました

```
cd ~/thingspeak
bundle install
sudo rake db:create
```

実行した結果、以下のようなエラーが出て上手くいきません

```
rake aborted!
NameError: uninitialized constant Bundler
/home/pi/thingspeak/config/boot.rb:9:in `rescue in <top (required)>'
/home/pi/thingspeak/config/boot.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
/home/pi/thingspeak/config/application.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
/home/pi/thingspeak/Rakefile:4:in `<top (required)>'

Caused by:
LoadError: cannot load such file -- bundler
/home/pi/thingspeak/config/boot.rb:7:in `<top (required)>'
/home/pi/thingspeak/config/application.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
/home/pi/thingspeak/Rakefile:4:in `<top (required)>'
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

```
bundle exec rake db:create
```

も試したのですが、

```
rake aborted!
NameError: uninitialized constant Mysql2::Client::LONG_PASSWORD
/home/pi/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0@thingspeak/gems/mysql2-0.3.10/lib/mysql2/client.rb:12:in `<class:Client>'
/home/pi/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0@thingspeak/gems/mysql2-0.3.10/lib/mysql2/client.rb:2:in `<module:Mysql2>'
/home/pi/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0@thingspeak/gems/mysql2-0.3.10/lib/mysql2/client.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
/home/pi/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0@thingspeak/gems/mysql2-0.3.10/lib/mysql2.rb:10:in `require'
/home/pi/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0@thingspeak/gems/mysql2-0.3.10/lib/mysql2.rb:10:in `<top (required)>'
/home/pi/thingspeak/config/application.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
/home/pi/thingspeak/Rakefile:4:in `require'
/home/pi/thingspeak/Rakefile:4:in `<top (required)>'
/home/pi/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0@thingspeak/gems/rake-12.3.3/exe/rake:27:in `<top (required)>'
/home/pi/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0@thingspeak/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:24:in `eval'
/home/pi/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0@thingspeak/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:24:in `<main>'
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

このようなエラーが表示されます

環境：
OS:Raspbian Buster 10.2
Ruby Version 2.1.0p0
Gem Version 2.1.0
RVM Version 1.29.9
Bundle Version 1.17.3

Ruby,MySQL等について初心者で至らぬ質問ですがよろしくお願いします

Answer (score 1, accepted):

元の`Gemfile.lock`では`mysql2`のバージョンが`0.3.16`になっていますが、エラーメッセージでは`0.3.10`が使われてるようです。`rake`のバージョンも`10.3.2`のはずが`12.3.3`が呼び出されていますし。

恐らくいろいろ試してる時に`bundle update`して`Gemfile.lock`を更新してしまったのではないかと思います。

> 但し依存関係の問題でTzinfo-dataはGemfileからコメントアウトしました。

と書かれていますが、具体的にどのような問題があったのでしょうか？

これくらい古いバージョンを使っていますと特定のGemだけバージョンを変えようとすると深みにハマってしまうことが多いのでどうにかして全部のバージョンを全く同じに整える方法を探したほうが早く解決できることが多いです。

それと`rvm`などのRubyの環境をホームディレクトリ以下に生成するものを使っている時は`rake`を`sudo`で呼び出すことは基本的にありません。むしろその事によって環境が破壊されることがありますので一度`rvm`から入れ直したほうがいいと思います。(私は`rvm`ではなく`rbenv`を使っているため、この点もし間違っていたらすいません。)